# How to invert this type of infinite series?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, inverse, inverse-function

If have a function $f$ given by a series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n,m = 0}^\infty u_{n,m} z^{n + m t}
$$
for some $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Is there an straightforward way (something similar to the inversion formula for Taylor series) to derive a similar series for $f^{-1}(z)$?

Comment: Lagrange inversion? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work in this case, since it's not exactly a Taylor series

Comment: What is the inversion formula for Taylor series ?

Comment: With $w:=z^t$, you in fact have a bivariate series $f(z,w)=\sum u_{n,m}z^nw^m$.

Comment: OK. Does that help me invert it?

Comment: Why would you want to find the inverse function of such a thing ? It won't have an expansion around $z=0$. If you meant $1/f(z)$ there is an easy solution $v_{l,k} =-\sum_{n\le l, m \le k, (n,m) \ne (0,0)} u_{n,m} v_{l-n,k-m}$

Comment: No I mean the inverse function. It will be invertible as a real-valued function on an interval $[0,\epsilon)$.